# Асинхронная загрузка большого количества файлов в в Java

Tags: java, android, mvp

Появилась задача реализовать асинхронную загрузку большого количества изображений с последующим их отображением в определённых местах интерфейса. Есть класс, назовём его условно `Model`, который отправляет запросы и сохраняет результат, есть класс, условно `Presenter`, который получает изображение от модели и дальше работает с ними, есть класс `EventBus`, который отправляет сообщение об окончании загрузки изображения в контроллер.

Собственно, вопрос, как наиболее корректно реализовать работу с большим количеством одновременных запросов? С потоками всё ясно, больше интересует то, как `Presenter`, получив сообщение об окончании загрузки, произведёт именно ту операцию с изображением, какую необходимо? Скажем, передаст в нужный метод `View` с нужными параметрами.

На текущий момент у меня есть только одна идея - присваивать каждому запросу id и по этому id определять, что нужно сделать с результатом. Является ли это нормальной практикой или есть более элегантные решения? 
Я знаю, что для этого можно использовать сторонние библиотеки, но меня интересует реализация с помощью стандартного набора Java.

Answer (score 1):

При асинхронной работе принято передавать некий параметр, который по завершению работы вернется обратно вместе с результатом. Обычно это некий объект, который идентифицирует конкретную работу.

Т.к. асинхронному методу все равно, что это за объект, то используют обобщение типов. И тогда вызывающая сторона указывает с каким типом она работает

Comment: Большое спасибо, примерно так я и думал поступить, но в силу того, что я начал изучение недавно, мне не совсем понятен второй абзац. Не могли бы вы продемонстрировать его на простом примере?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так.
До запуска загрузки создайте список картинок для загрузки, потом подготовьте  пустые файлы под заливку в них скачанных картинок, сделайте из них тоже список.
Таким образом у Вас будет 2 списка: урлы и  соответствующие им картинки.

```
List<String> listUrl; //список урлов с картинками;
List<File> listImg; //список пустышек для заливки туда скачанных картинок;
```

Далее запускаете загрузчик картинок (здесь код загрузчика привел тот которым самому приходилось пользоваться) и передаете пару: `url`в виде строки и `file`.

```
List<String> listUrl;
List<File> listImg;

private void startLoad() {
    for (int i = 0; i < listUrl.size(); i++) {

        startLoading(listUrl.get(i), listImg.get(i));
    }
}

private void startLoading(String pathImg, File imgFile) {

    try {
        URL url = new URL(pathImg);//Create Download URl
        HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();//Open Url Connection
        c.setRequestMethod("GET");//Set Request Method to "GET" since we are grtting data
        c.connect();//connect the URL Connection

        //If Connection response is not OK then show Logs
        if (c.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Server returned HTTP " + c.getResponseCode()
                    + " " + c.getResponseMessage());

        }

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(imgFile);//Get OutputStream for NewFile Location

        InputStream is = c.getInputStream();//Get InputStream for connection

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];//Set buffer type
        int len1 = 0;//init length
        while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);//Write new file
        }

        //Close all connection after doing task
        fos.close();
        is.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        imgFile = null;
    }
}
```

Таким образом картинка №1 со списка `listUrl` будет залита в заранее подготовленный файл №1 со списка `listImg`.

Так как Вы сказали что с потоками все понятно, то код загрузчика приведен как пример.

Answer (score 0):

Самым элегантным решением будет использование RxJava. EventBus использовать не рекомендую, со временем код превращается в нечитаемую лапшу